# Where can I find the full path of my imported package / module? angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, import, angular-material

I'm using angular 9 on vs code.
I've noticed that in the earlier versions of angular, whenever you wanted to import a package / module, it was enough to specify just part of the path and things worked.

In angular 9, I need to specify the full path to a module - which is hard to know what is the path.

for example,
right now I am looking for the full path of `BrowserAnimationsModule` i tried looking online but all I could find was:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/material'
```

So, how do I find the specific path to import every time I'm using new module?

Comment: import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

Comment: Thank you! it worked!
but how do i know the path every time i want to import something?

Comment: @HilaGrossbard you could try installing an extension like npm Intellisense to help with this.

Comment: @RobBailey Thank you for your offer, I tried it and it does suggests me some full path, but unfortunately it's still not giving me the full path of the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an angular beginner I was looking for some way to find the full path of a package.

The solution I have found is:

1. Search the package name is Google.
2. Select the angular.io result (almost always the first result).
3. At the top of the article you can see the full path written in a bit different format.

For example, the package i was looking for was `BrowserAnimationsModule`.

[image: image from angular.io]

Eventually, the full path I used in my `app.module.ts` file was:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```